# Function Pointer Array Initialization

Tags: c++, arduino, initialization

Consider an array of function pointers within a class in c++14:

```
class myClass {
    myClass();
    void (* myFunctions [5])();
}
```

This array will be populated in other parts of the code, and it is not guaranteed that the array will actually hold as many function pointers as it can (5 in the example). So before calling any of the functions referred to by the array i'd need to check whether the pointer I'm trying to use actually stores something. My idea was to compare the pointer against `nullptr`, and assume that it points to a valid function if the test fails, i.e. in some function of that class:

```
if(myFunctions[x] == nullptr) {
    // Handle error
    return;
}

// Use myFunctions[x]
```

I was wondering if I need to initialize the array before making that kind of speculation. How is this array initialized if I only write the above two lines of code? Can I assume something like `myFunctions[x] ==  nullptr` is true in that case? Or do I need to do an explicit initialization like the following one?

```
for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    myFunctions[i] = nullptr;
```

I've found the [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) page on cppreference.com, but as I'm learning c++ and I'm still very unexperienced I wasn't able to understand whether this applies in my case. I've also tried to test the pointers by printing their value without assigning any function address and got `0 0 0 0 0`, but I don't think the result is reliable: this program is for a microcontroller, and it's possible that the "garbage" values on the stack are all `0`s since it is emptied during each code upload.

Comment: You have to initialize it.

Comment: Check array initializer list

Comment: Not the question, but when you think of function pointers in c++, I'd suggest to first think of whether polymorphism and dynamic binding is more appropriate to express what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you *have to* initialize the array, although I'd encourage you to do that. The reason why the array is default-initialized in your case is because you provide a constructor and do not mention the data member in the initializer list (cf. [cppreference/default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)):

> **Default initialization is performed in three situations:**
>
> ...
>
> 3) when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a
>   constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.

Hence, default initialization will take place.

Anyway, in order to express that you rely on a data member to be "zero" without enforcing in other ways that non-initialized entries will not be accessed, I'd make the initialization explicit, e.g.

```
class myClass {
    myClass();
    void (* myFunctions [5])() = { };
}
```